GCP Services (GCE, GKE, SQL) shown as "Networking" in Billing reports
This is how my billing report looks, grouped by Service:

In above period of time, I was using 4 services in my GCP project:

a GKE standard cluster
a GCE VM
an SQL postgresql instance
a temporary GKE autopilot cluster, only in between 1-4 June.

The question is why all my billings from GKE standard cluster, GCE, and SQL all categorized as "Networking" service?
Edit: This is how it looks if grouped by SKU


Hi can you add more information on how you are filtering these values. What we can see from the graph is that all the services that you have used are being listed with their bills as you can see there are separate legends for each service. There is one more possibility that the graph might be showing the summation of the egress charge generated by each service. We can help further if you could provide more information on how you are generating these reports.

Hi, sorry for the incomplete image. I edited the picture in the question :)
I didn't change the filter at all except the "Group by" field to "Service".

Hi Rahadian Panji this official documentation gives you a detailed  explanation on how to interpret these billing reports. The current report shows the charges generated by the data transfer by each service

The billing chart which you have attached in the above description shows the separate billing for each service, as you can see you haven’t applied any extra filter like group by service=networking that means the bills are for individual services and they are not being categorized as Network service.
As per that bill report which you have generated, your charges for each service are as follow:

Networking service - $11.72

GKE - $0.49

Compute - $0.00

Cloud SQL - $0.00


The $12.21 bill which you are seeing is the summation of the charges of each service but it’s not showing remaining services as a subpart of networking service.
If you are still having some doubts, it is suggested to contact the dedicated support team as they have more tools to analyze this and can provide you with a more  apt response.
